# onjsconfirm not working for api 17

Tags: android, webview, popup

It has been a week since I've started to look for a solution but none of what I've found have worked for me. I have an app with webviews and a popup isn't showing up like it does on browser. This popup asks the user to confirm if he wants to be redirected (I haven't created the popup, it is already in the website).
So I tried with onjsconfirm but it doesn't detect the popup, it does nothing...

My goal is tu get the url where the user is getting redirected, I don't really need to load it.

So please if you have a solution, I really need help!

Answer (score 0):

***better late than never***

To get the url where the user is redirected you can use:

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // You have the new url here!
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Don't forget add the webclient to the webView

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

If you want to catch the pop-up you have to add a webChromeClient ( you can add both )

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```